# Php + AJAX, how to hide file name?

Tags: php, ajax

Here's my code.

`getuser.php`:

```
...
    while ($result = @mssql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
        foreach ($result as $item => $value) {
            if (is_null($value)) {
                $result[$item] = 'Empty';
            }
        }

       foreach ($result as $result => $data) {
            echo '' . $result . '' . '' . $data . '';
       }
    }

    echo "";
}

mssql_close($con);
?>
```

`index.php`:

```
function showUser(str) {
    if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET","getchar.php?q="+str,true); xmlhttp.send();
}
```

This is an instant search, to find a user, it gets their info as soon as it's typed.
Basically I want to know, if there's a way I can hide the filename of the PHP page (getuser.php) in the AJAX script (xml part), so people can't just go to www.example.com/getuser.php?q=user
and get the information. Would I have to add a && statement to see if the person logged in is an admin? so like

```
if(isset($_GET)) && isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    // do code
}
```

Comment: Please add line breaks and indent your code properly. More members here will be willing to help if your code is readable.

Answer (score 1):

No. But you can just detect the AJAX request in your PHP file so users can't navigate to that page in their browser.  Like so:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 'xmlhttprequest' == strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) {
    // put code here
}
```

---

##### Edit 2022:

Now in PHP 7+ using the null coalescing operator

```
if ('xmlhttprequest' === strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ?? null)) {
    // put code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The browser has to know the URL it is going to fetch, and it is trivial to find out what URLs browsers are requesting (by looking at the Net tab in a debugger if nothing else).

Comment: I checked in the Network tab for many websites but no name is shown there... http://smartlink.co.in/SUPPORT   - here when I change the Category dropdown option then the file name is same as current URL

Comment: @sqlchild — That site made two HTTP requests that were visible in the Net tab when I changed the category dropdown: http://note.io/1sLbzvj